# Как достоверно определить есть ли тачскрин на устройстве?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Прошу прощения если вопрос избит, но очень хотелось бы получить четкий рациональный ответ.

Как достоверно определить есть ли на устройстве просмотра тачскрин?

js:

```
if (%тачскрин%) { $('#touch_menu').show(); } else { $('#default_menu').show(); }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com). Там есть определение типа устройства. Также есть описание и страница тестов как раз по этому поводу: [Modernizr Touch tests](http://modernizr.github.io/Modernizr/touch.html).

```
if (Modernizr.touch){
   // Touch device
} else {
   // Not a touch device
}
```

А вообще в случае с меню думаю лучше оринтироваться на ширину экрана, используя [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) для показа/скрытия нужного меню.

Answer (score 1):

```
var isTouch = "ontouchstart" in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints;
```