# Как в jquery сделать так чтобы скрипт работал только на устройствах с тачскрином?

Tags: javascript, jquery, экран

Есть некий jquery-скрип, который должен работать только на мобильных устройствах. Нетрудно конечно обернуть его в конструкцию где указать, чтобы он срабатывал только при ширине экрана меньше какой-то величины. Однако сейчас девайсы могут быть с достаточно большой шириной экрана и при этом иметь тачскрин.

Вот у меня собственно и появился вопрос. А можно ли в jquery каким-то образом сделать так, чтобы скрипт работал только на устройствах с тачскрином?

Comment: [Аналогичная тема](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819886)  обсуждалась. Думаю, что вам подойдёт.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как достоверно определить есть ли тачскрин на устройстве?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/245275/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5)

Comment: Спасибо, интересный подход. Попробую в этом направлении двигаться.